# Is it possible to create sequence in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I am developing product named HMIS (Hospital Management Information System)

I want to create UHID no (Unique Hospital Identity No)?

How can I create alphanumeric unique no that can be shared accross two tables in mysql?

(Above scenario can be possible in Oracle DB because it allows me to create sequence.)

Comment: mysql has an auto_increment option for a primary key

Comment: yes, but scope of auto_increment is valid upto only one column in one table

Comment: i think you need to rethink the structure of your database then, if they share the same key they should either be one table. or one table should have a foreign key to the main one.

Comment: Cant you generate the unique code in your application using an uuid or something like that?